# clean at all stages url

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-rewriting, slash

The problem is a slash `/` "`example.ru/aboutus/`" translates into a "**500 server error**" and appends `http://example.ru/aboutus/.html` at the end of uri.

### .HTACCESS

```
## www.site/index.html ==> site/index.html ##
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

## index.html ==> index ##
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

## index/ ==> index ##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

but into enter slash, me drop in to 500 page error

---

### HTML

```
in the html code pages do not have any links .html extension
`<a href=aboutus>About Us</a>` except `<a href=index.html>index</a>`
```

### QUESTION

- (is it right?)
- (can canonical in html help?)
- (whether you want to Disallow the Robots.txt * .html?)

how to solve the problem that there are no duplicates, so that all pages have been without slashes and extensions .html? all that is needed for seo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**found a solution**

```
Options All -ExecCGI -Multiviews -Indexes -Includes +FollowSymLinks

# This tag ensures the rewrite module is loaded
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # enable the rewrite engine
  RewriteEngine On
  # Set your root directory
  RewriteBase /

# remove the www extension
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

  # remove the .html extension
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
  RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]

  # remove index and reference the directory
  RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

  # remove trailing slash if not a directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

  # forward request to html file, **but don't redirect (bot friendly)**
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
  RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

[author](https://www.alexscotton.com/post/rewrite-html-file-extensions-with-htaccess)